# Problems Moving Between Xcode & Visual Studio

Tags: c++, xcode, visual-studio-2012, compiler-errors

I have searched the forums and not found an answer specific to my current problem. I am taking a C++ class whose professor mainly compiles our assignments on a Windows machine running Visual Studio. My primary platform for coding is Xcode on my MacBook Pro.

My code runs just fine in Xcode. For my assignments, I usually copy and paste that code into a .txt file and turn it in. He then takes that code, copies it into Visual Studio and compiles. Even on the simplest code, he always returns some type of error or strange behavior that I just do not get in Xcode.

For testing, I also run my code in two other compilers (QT & the online compiler C++ shell). It always runs fine.

Can anyone help me figure out what the issue is? I can provide an example of code that runs in Xcode but fails miserably in Visual Studio if you need. Just let me know.

```
//TIC TAC TOE lets 2 human players compete to win at the classic game.

//libraries being used
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <math.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>

//setting namespace to be used
using namespace std;

//function prototype declarations
void splashScreen();
void askForUserNames(string& user1, string& user2);
void validateUserName(string& user);
void displayGrid(string& user1, string& user2);
void validatePlayersMove(string& playersMove, string& currentUser);
void playerMakeMove(string& currentUser, string& userMove);
void checkPositionAvailability (string grid1[], string grid2[],string grid3[], string& userMove, string& currentUser, int userTurn);
void validateInput(string& playAgain);
void checkWin(bool& itsATie, bool& whoWon, string grid1[], string grid2[], string grid3[]);




//main function that calls all of the other functions.
int main()
{
    string name1 = "";
    string name2 = "";
    string playAgain = "y";
    splashScreen();
    cout << "\n";
    askForUserNames(name1, name2);
    cout << "\n\n";
    while (playAgain == "y" || playAgain == "Y")
    {
        displayGrid(name1,name2);
        cout << "Would you like to play again? Type 'y/n'" << endl;
        cout << ">>";
        getline(cin,playAgain);
        validateInput(playAgain);
    }
    return 0;
}

//prints the welcoming message for user and first instructions to enter user name
void splashScreen()
{
    cout << "**************************************" << endl;
    cout << "*****        TIC TAC TOE        ******" << endl;
    cout << "*****   By xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx    ******" << endl;
    cout << "**************************************" << endl;
    cout << "**        ENTER PLAYER NAMES        **" << endl;
    cout << "**        and press <ENTER>.        **" << endl;
    cout << "**************************************" << endl;
    cout << "**************************************" << endl;
}

void askForUserNames(string& user1, string& user2)
{
    cout << "Player1 >>";
    getline(cin, user1);
    validateUserName(user1);
    cout << "Thank you, " << user1 << endl;
    cout << "Player2 >>";
    getline(cin,user2);
    validateUserName(user2);
    cout << "Thank you, " << user2 << endl;

}

//validates user name input. accepts only letters.
void validateUserName(string& user)
{
    int counter = 0;
    int stringLength;

    stringLength = user.length();

    while (counter < stringLength || stringLength == 0)
    {
        if (!isalpha(user[counter]))
        {
            cout << "No special characters. No spaces. Only letters. Please try again.\n";
            cout << ">>";
            getline(cin,user);
            stringLength = user.length();
            counter = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            counter++;
        }
    }

}

//validates whether the playAgain option in main function contains appropriate letters (Y/y, N/n)
void validateInput(string& playAgain)
{
    int counter = 0;
    int stringLength;

    stringLength = playAgain.length();

    while (counter < stringLength || stringLength == 0)
    {
        if (!isalpha(playAgain[counter]))
        {
            cout << "No special characters. No spaces. Please try again.\n";
            cout << ">>";
            getline(cin,playAgain);
            stringLength = playAgain.length();
            counter = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            counter++;
        }
        if (playAgain != "Y" && playAgain != "y" && playAgain != "N" && playAgain != "n")
        {
            cout << "Choose Y/y or N/n. Please try again.\n";
            cout << ">>";
            getline(cin,playAgain);
            stringLength = playAgain.length();
            counter = 0;
        }
    }

}

//displays game grid and allows users to make moves
void displayGrid(string& user1, string& user2)
{
    const int ARRAY_SIZE = 3;
    string topRow[ARRAY_SIZE] = {"0","1","2"};
    string middleRow[ARRAY_SIZE] = {"3","4","5"};
    string bottomRow[ARRAY_SIZE] = {"6","7","8"};
    int userTurn = 1;
    string continu = "y";
    string userMove="";
    bool whoWon = false;
    bool itsATie;

    while (continu == "y" || continu == "Y")
    {
        cout << "TIC-TAC-TOE" << endl;
        cout << "  |-----|" << endl;
        cout << "  |";

        for (int count = 0; count < ARRAY_SIZE; count++)
        {
            cout << topRow[count] << "|";
        }
        cout << endl;
        cout << "  |";
        for (int count = 0; count < ARRAY_SIZE; count++)
        {
            cout << middleRow[count] << "|";
        }

        cout << endl;
        cout << "  |";

        for (int count = 0; count < ARRAY_SIZE; count++)
        {
            cout << bottomRow[count] << "|";
        }
        cout << endl;
        cout << "  |-----|" << endl;

        bool whoWon;

        //changes user turn & determines win or tie
        if(userTurn == 1)
        {
            checkWin(itsATie, whoWon,topRow, middleRow, bottomRow);
            if(whoWon == true)
            {
                cout << user2 << " won this round!" << endl;
                continu = "n";
            }
            else if (whoWon == false && itsATie == true)
            {
                cout << "It's a tie!" << endl;
                continu = "n";
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "\nIt is " << user1 << "'s turn; You are 'X'\nGive me your best move! Enter a free number." << endl;
                playerMakeMove(user1,userMove);
                checkPositionAvailability(topRow,middleRow,bottomRow,userMove, user1, userTurn);

            }
            userTurn = 2;


        }

        else
        {
            if(userTurn == 2)
            {
                checkWin(itsATie, whoWon,topRow, middleRow, bottomRow);
                if(whoWon == true)
                {
                    cout << user1 << " won this round!" << endl;
                    continu = "n";
                }
                else if (whoWon == false && itsATie == true)
                {
                    cout << "It's a tie!" << endl;
                    continu = "n";
                }

                else
                {
                    cout << "\nIt is " << user2 << "'s turn; You are 'Y'\nGive me your best move! Enter a free number." << endl;
                    playerMakeMove(user2,userMove);
                    checkPositionAvailability(topRow,middleRow,bottomRow,userMove, user2, userTurn);

                }
                userTurn = 1;

            }

        }

    }

}

//accepts player input for moves
void playerMakeMove(string& currentUser, string& userMove)
{
    cout << ">>";
    getline(cin,userMove);
    validatePlayersMove(userMove,currentUser);
}

//validates player's input for moves
void validatePlayersMove(string& userMove, string& currentUser)
{
    int counter = 0;
    int stringLength;
    string functionPass = "n";

    stringLength = userMove.length();

    while (functionPass == "n")
    {
        while (counter < stringLength || stringLength == 0)
        {
            if (!isdigit(userMove[counter]))
            {
                cout << "Choose from selections listed. No spaces. It is still " << currentUser << "'s turn.\n";
                cout << ">>";
                getline(cin,userMove);
                stringLength = userMove.length();
                counter = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                counter++;
            }

        }
        int integerMove = stoi(userMove);
        if (integerMove < 0 || integerMove >8)
        {
            cout << "Choose from the selections listed ONLY" << endl;
            cout << ">>";
            getline(cin,userMove);
            stringLength = userMove.length();
            counter = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            functionPass = "y";
        }
    }


}

//checks the availability of positions
void checkPositionAvailability (string grid1[], string grid2[], string grid3[], string& userMove, string& currentUser, int userTurn)
{
    const int SIZE = 3;
    string numberAvailable = "n";
    int count=0;
    while (count < SIZE)
    {
        for (count = 0; count < SIZE; count++)
        {
            if (grid1[count] == userMove || grid2[count] == userMove || grid3[count] == userMove)
            {
                numberAvailable = "y";
                count = SIZE;
            }
            else
            {
                numberAvailable = "n";
            }

        }


        if (numberAvailable == "y")
        {
            for (int count = 0; count < SIZE; count++)
            {
                if (grid1[count] == userMove)
                {
                    if(userTurn == 1)
                    {
                        grid1[count] = "X";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        grid1[count] = "Y";
                    }
                }

            }

            for (int count = 0; count < SIZE; count++)
            {
                if (grid2[count] == userMove)
                {
                    if(userTurn == 1)
                    {
                        grid2[count] = "X";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        grid2[count] = "Y";
                    }
                }

            }

            for (int count = 0; count < SIZE; count++)
            {
                if (grid3[count] == userMove)
                {
                    if(userTurn == 1)
                    {
                        grid3[count] = "X";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        grid3[count] = "Y";
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        else
        {
            if(numberAvailable == "n")
            {
                cout << "That number is no longer available. Please choose a different number. It is still " << currentUser << "'s turn." << endl;
                playerMakeMove(currentUser, userMove);
                count = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}

//checks whether the game has been won or, if all spaces are unavailable, whether there has been a tie
void checkWin(bool& itsATie, bool& whoWon,string grid1[], string grid2[], string grid3[])
{
    int counterHorizontal = 0;
    int counterVertical = 0;
    int counterDiagonal = 0;
    whoWon = false;
    itsATie = false;


    if (grid1[counterHorizontal] == "X")
    {
        counterHorizontal++;

        if(grid1[counterHorizontal] == "X")
        {
            counterHorizontal++;

            if(grid1[counterHorizontal] == "X")
            {
                whoWon = true;
            }
        }
    }

    counterHorizontal = 0;

    if (grid1[counterHorizontal] == "Y")
    {
        counterHorizontal++;

        if(grid1[counterHorizontal] == "Y")
        {
            counterHorizontal++;

            if(grid1[counterHorizontal] == "Y")
            {
                whoWon = true;
            }
        }
    }

    counterHorizontal = 0;

    if (grid2[counterHorizontal] == "X")
    {
        counterHorizontal++;

        if(grid2[counterHorizontal] == "X")
        {
            counterHorizontal++;

            if(grid2[counterHorizontal] == "X")
            {
                whoWon = true;
            }
        }
    }

    counterHorizontal = 0;

    if (grid2[counterHorizontal] == "Y")
    {
        counterHorizontal++;

        if(grid2[counterHorizontal] == "Y")
        {
            counterHorizontal++;

            if(grid2[counterHorizontal] == "Y")
            {
                whoWon = true;
            }
        }
    }

    counterHorizontal = 0;

    if (grid3[counterHorizontal] == "X")
    {
        counterHorizontal++;

        if(grid3[counterHorizontal] == "X")
        {
            counterHorizontal++;

            if(grid3[counterHorizontal] == "X")
            {
                whoWon = true;
            }
        }
    }

    counterHorizontal = 0;

    if (grid3[counterHorizontal] == "Y")
    {
        counterHorizontal++;

        if(grid3[counterHorizontal] == "Y")
        {
            counterHorizontal++;

            if(grid3[counterHorizontal] == "Y")
            {
                whoWon = true;
            }
        }
    }

    if(grid1[counterVertical] == "X")
    {
        if(grid2[counterVertical] == "X")
        {
            if(grid3[counterVertical] == "X")
            {
                whoWon = true;
            }
        }
    }
    counterVertical++;

    if(grid1[counterVertical] == "X")
    {
        if(grid2[counterVertical] == "X")
        {
            if(grid3[counterVertical] == "X")
            {
                whoWon = true;
            }
        }
    }
    counterVertical++;

    if(grid1[counterVertical] == "X")
    {
        if(grid2[counterVertical] == "X")
        {
            if(grid3[counterVertical] == "X")
            {
                whoWon = true;
            }
        }
    }
    counterVertical++;
    counterVertical = 0;

    if(grid1[counterVertical] == "Y")
    {
        if(grid2[counterVertical] == "Y")
        {
            if(grid3[counterVertical] == "Y")
            {
                whoWon = true;
            }
        }
    }
    counterVertical++;

    if(grid1[counterVertical] == "Y")
    {
        if(grid2[counterVertical] == "Y")
        {
            if(grid3[counterVertical] == "Y")
            {
                whoWon = true;
            }
        }
    }
    counterVertical++;

    if(grid1[counterVertical] == "Y")
    {
        if(grid2[counterVertical] == "Y")
        {
            if(grid3[counterVertical] == "Y")
            {
                whoWon = true;
            }
        }
    }

    if(grid1[counterDiagonal] == "X")
    {
        counterDiagonal++;

        if(grid2[counterDiagonal] == "X")
        {
            counterDiagonal++;

            if(grid3[counterDiagonal] == "X")
            {
                whoWon = true;
            }
        }
    }
    counterDiagonal = 0;

    if(grid1[counterDiagonal] == "Y")
    {
        counterDiagonal++;

        if(grid2[counterDiagonal] == "Y")
        {
            counterDiagonal++;

            if(grid3[counterDiagonal] == "Y")
            {
                whoWon = true;
            }
        }
    }
    counterDiagonal = 2;

    if(grid1[counterDiagonal] == "X")
    {
        counterDiagonal--;

        if(grid2[counterDiagonal] == "X")
        {
            counterDiagonal--;

            if(grid3[counterDiagonal] == "X")
            {
                whoWon = true;
            }
        }
    }

    counterDiagonal = 2;

    if(grid1[counterDiagonal] == "Y")
    {
        counterDiagonal--;

        if(grid2[counterDiagonal] == "Y")
        {
            counterDiagonal--;

            if(grid3[counterDiagonal] == "Y")
            {
                whoWon = true;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int tieCount = 0; tieCount < 3; tieCount++)
    {
        if (grid1[tieCount] == "X" || grid1[tieCount] == "Y")
        {
            itsATie = true;
        }
        else
        {
            itsATie = false;
            tieCount = 3;
        }
        if (grid2[tieCount] == "X" || grid2[tieCount] == "Y")
        {
            itsATie = true;
        }
        else
        {
            itsATie = false;
            tieCount = 3;
        }
        if (grid3[tieCount] == "X" || grid3[tieCount] == "Y")
        {
            itsATie = true;
        }
        else
        {
            itsATie = false;
            tieCount = 3;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Also, why not try this online VS compiler: http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/

Comment: Just updated the code and about to try the online compiler as well.

Comment: Compiles just fine in the online VS.

Comment: I get one warning on Mac OS X with clang: `pops.cpp:147:10: warning: unused variable 'whoWon' [-Wunused-variable]` - you should be seeing this same warning in Xcode.

Comment: I do get that warning, but the program still successfully compiles and runs in Xcode.

Comment: OK - get into the habit of fixing warnings though - often they are harmless but sometimes they can highlight something subtle and dangerous, even if the code *appears* to run OK.

Comment: It would be helpful to know what the errors are as I'm not going to install VS 2012 to check for you.  Your teacher might consider updating to a newer version too.

Comment: I bet that you use C++11 standard [(picture)](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uOLQV.png) but your teacher is running older Visual Studio and uses older standards. Talk to him/her and politely ask if you can demonstrate using your machine... thats what I do all the time (if there is compilation problem on teachers side) + code is on GitHub.

Comment: @RetiredNinja The exact error he gets is

Unhandled exception at 0x5759D455(msvcr110d.dll) in Project2.exe: 0xC00000005: Access violation reading location 0xCCCCCCCC

Usually, I can get him to run in a different compiler, but he has a lot of students and I think I may be the only person having this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible that your teacher is running the code in debug mode and Visual Studio is doing more bounds checking (or failing faster due to allocated values being initialized to 0xcccccccc instead of being left uninitialized).

For example, this code, in checkWin:

```
    else
    {
        itsATie = false;
        tieCount = 3;
    }
    if (grid2[tieCount] == "X" || grid2[tieCount] == "Y")
```

sets `tieCount` to 3 then immediately uses it as an index into an array of length 3, leading to an array overflow. This is Undefined Behavior, and anything could happen. Possibly due to the memory layout in Xcode you have been (un)lucky and `grid2[3]` happens to be at the same location as `grid3[0]`.

I guess you could try running through valgrind, which may help pick up these sort of errors.

Comment: You are absolutely right. As I wrote this program a bit ago, I couldn't exactly remember the logic of why I would write it that way, but just recalled that we weren't allowed to use any break statements.

From the looks of it this should have failed a long time ago, but for whatever reason did not. As you said "(un)lucky". I guess I should just try running everything through as many compilers as possible to see what catches. Is there a way to run a more rigorous debug in Xcode?

Comment: Not that I know of, for Xcode anyway. You could switch to using std::array and the `at` method, which does bounds checking, but that is a fair amount of work.

Comment: Here is another small example

``void populateArray(StudentType students[], ifstream &openFile){
 int index = 0;
 string number;
 while (!openFile.eof()){
  getline(openFile, students[index].fname, ' ');
  getline(openFile, students[index].lname, ' ');
  getline(openFile, number);
  students[index].testScore = stoi(number);
  index++;
 }
 openFile.close();
}``

Comment: This function is supposed to take an array of structures and populate it with data from an open text file. It works in Xcode with no errors. In Visual Studio I have to write it this way to work.

openFile >> students[index].fname >> students[index].lname >> students[index].testScore;

Comment: Could be a lot of things - the input file may have an extra blank line at the end, the array may not be big enough. You should put some trace writes in to see what is causing the issue.